# Sendmail Error : opendaemonsocket: daemon TLSMTA: cannot bind: Address already in use

Tags: sockets, email, ssl, sendmail, smtps

I am installing sendmail/dovecot on my mail sever.

I edited file /etc/mail/sendmail.mc

and add the below lines to make sure the domain name is used in sending mail

```
#add for domain email  by deo malamo
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `desaonline.co.tz')dnl
FEATURE(`relay_entire_domain')dnl
#end add domail based email by deo malamo
```

i installed and Used tls/ssl from Let's Encrypt

```
#add for Let's Encrypt ssl by deo malamo
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`CERT_DIR', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.desaonline.co.tz/')dnl
define(`confCACERT', `CERT_DIR/chain.pem')dnl
define(`confCACERT_PATH',`/etc/ssl/certs/')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_CERT', `CERT_DIR/cert.pem')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_KEY', `CERT_DIR/privkey.pem')dnl
define(`confSERVER_CERT', `CERT_DIR/cert.pem')dnl
define(`confSERVER_KEY', `CERT_DIR/privkey.pem')dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtps, Name=TLSMTA, M=s')dnl
#DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl
#DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
#end add Let's Encrypt ssl by dmalamo
```

**MY PROBLEM is the ports 25,465 and 587 are coming up and then shutdown because of port already in use ,Can any one assist me to fix this problem?**

When i save the config (/etc/mail/sendmail.mc) and restart sendmail ,port 465 seems to be used and shutdown the whole outgoing ports 25,465 and 587.

logs file have the below entries

```
daemon TLSMTA: problem creating SMTP socket
Feb  9 13:26:43 mail sm-mta[20646]: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon TLSMTA: cannot bind: Address already in use


NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon TLSMTA: cannot bind: Address already in use
daemon TLSMTA: problem creating SMTP socket
NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon TLSMTA: server SMTP socket wedged: exiting
```

*MY PROBLEM is the ports 25,465 and 587 are coming up and then shutdown because of port already in use ,Can any one assist me to fix this problem?*

Answer (score 0):

Short list to check...

1st) have You compiled sendmail.mc into sendmail.cf ?

2nd) TLSMTA: cannot bind: Address already in use... means that one process already use this port (smtps: 465), 

 - check who is using port (e.g. "netstat -lntp|grep 465")

 - and stop this, sometimes port can be in use by connection, maybe instead restart You should: stop, wait few sec./minutes and then start sendmail

 - "netstat -lntp|grep sendmail" can be usefull to see sendmail's listening ports

 - before start be sure that ports are not occupied (not in use)

 - problem may also be in SELINUX (investigate how to allow program to use ports)

Regards

K.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).